# Align text with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>​
```

I amending the width of the text so it fits into 220px. This causes the text to wrap underneath the radio button if it is of a certain length. As shown in this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/8/

The options should wrap to right of radio button as shown in diagram :

[image]

Is this possible ? I think I need to amend the class "pds-answer-span" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this style on CSS panel

```
.pds-input-label { width: 85% !important }
.pds-input-label, .pds-answer-input { float: left;  } 
.pds-answer-group { height: auto; overflow: hidden; /* float clearing */ }
```

you achieve the desired effect

Comment: Personally I would also add a margin-top:-5px; to the .pds-input-label style rule for this.

Comment: yes but maybe it's better do it on `.pds-answer-group` element (since it's grouping both the elements)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/11/

```
.pds-answer-input { margin-top: 4px; }

.pds-answer-input,
.pds-input-label { display: inline-block; max-width: 170px; }
```

Comment: inline-block shouldn't be used if you don't want it to break in older IE versions

Comment: @aowie1 Good point. The solution - change `<p>` to `<span>` and `inline-block` will work even in IE6 - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
```

add this (where 100px is your desired width)

```
#PDI_container6352993 .pds-input-label { 
    width 100px; 
}
```